# jax-rs Cual es la diferencia entre usar pathParam y queryParam en un servicio web?

Tags: java, rest

Si tengo este código de un servicio rest en java
JAX-RS

```
 @Path("/message")
 public class ExampleRestService {
 @GET
 @Path("/test/")
 public Response printeMessage(@PathParam("param") String mvar
        ){      
    String resp = "Mensaje restfull de respuesta es : "+ mvar ; 
    return Response.status(200).entity(resp).build();
}   

}
```

¿Que implicaciones tiene si se cambiara la anotacion PathParam por QueryParam, con respecto a la generación de la url del recurso y el paso de parametros ?

Answer (score 2):

### PathParam

Es un parámetro que forma parte de la ruta del recurso REST. Por ejemplo:
https://www.example.com/test/14 donde *14* sería **PathParam**

### QueryParam

Es un parámetro que está en la parte de consulta, o query string. Por ejemplo:
https://www.example.com/test?id=14 donde *id=14* sería **QueryParam**

A tu pregunta de si cambiaría la url del recurso, ya ves que sí ya que, además de no formar parte de la ruta sino de la parte de consulta, se prefija el nombre del parámetro

Comment: Gracias Javi por tu aclaracion fue muy util